# What is the difference between runtime headers and springboard headers?

Tags: iphone, ios, header, tweak

What I know so far is that the runtime headers are inside the framework folder, and that you must class-dump your idevice to find the springboard headers. But what is the difference? I am working on a tweak and I don't know what headers to use, so this is confusing me a bit. For instance, if you want to add an object to the statusbar, what headers should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you will need to class-dump the SpringBoard headers or use an already dumped set such as this one:
https://github.com/Fr0stDev/SpringBoard-iOS5-Headers

As for which header to use, that usually involves doing some digging around. I'd suggest starting with `SBStatusManager.h`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do this (add item to the status bar), but you also might want to look [here](http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=UIKit.framework&header=UIStatusBarServer.h) for `UIStatusBarServer`.  This class is not part of Springboard, per se, but appears to be part of the UIKit framework.  It appears to have a method to `addStatusBarItem`.  If I had to guess based on its name, it might be a framework service that listens for clients to add things to the status bar, which is what you want to do.